# Regular Expression - can't checking for special characters [ ]

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to check for the following characters: ( ) { } [ ]

The following code takes what the user has entered and console logs a message depending on whether they have entered an invalid character. The problem I am having is that I cannot get it to check for both [ ] characters - the code below checks for [ but not ]

```
 var nameString = $("#name").val();
    var  regexp =  /[(){}[]/;
    var invalidCharacters = nameString.match(regexp);
        if(invalidCharacters){
                console.log('Contains invalid character');
                } else{
               console.log('DOES NOT contain an invalid character');
           }
```

How do I add ] and keep the regex valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[\]({})]
```

You need to escape one of them so that another bracket range does not appear `[` and `]`.

It should not form `[[]`==>this creates problem.use `[[\]` now its fine

Comment: +1. I hope your answer gets accepted, to be honest. Mine will only cause confusion.

Comment: @AndrewCheong thanx.but yours serves the purpose too.Lets see how OP takes it :)

Comment: I understand this better whereas @AndrewCheong's looks more funky, both plus :)

Answer (score 5):

You must place the `]` in the beginning, like so,

```
var  regexp =  /[](){}[]/;
```

Now, understandably, this looks weird. It looks like an empty character class, `[]`, followed by pairs of brackets, `()`, `{}`, and `[]`. But believe it or not, it's actually the standard in regular expressions to *disregard the `]` as indicating the end of a character class **if it's the first character present***. Therefore the above is actually a character class for the characters `](){}[`.

You might also rearrange that as `][(){}`, but the regex still looks confusing:

```
var  regexp =  /[][(){}]/;
```

See, now it looks like *two* character classes—an empty one, and another for the characters `(){}`—but again, that's just what it *looks* like, and the above actually works too—it's the set of characters `][(){}`.

The thing is, most people don't know about this aspect of character classes, and so you'll only end up confusing others who read your code. I recommend simply escaping the `]`, as @vks answers:

```
var  regexp =  /[(){}[\]]/;
```

This will be understood by all.

Comment: Good answer. +1 for pointing out that although you _can_ place it unescaped at the start, its still better to go ahead and escape it anyway.